# Checkbox on Opportunity to check and uncheck account of similar field

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, checkbox

Let me try this again.

NDA Signed is a checkbox that I have on Account and Opportunity.

When I check or uncheck this box on either object I need it to update the opposite object.

example 1: I have NDA checked on the opportunity, once saved I need the Account checkbox to checked as well

example 2: If I Uncheck the box on Account, I need it to do the same thing to any and all opportunities underneath the account.

example 3: If I check the box on account, I need it to check this box for all opportunities under the account

example 4: If I uncheck the box on opportunity I need it to uncheck on account as well.

Can I do this with a workflow?

Or do I need a trigger? if I need a trigger, I have never written one before can someone help me in that area?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with what you're proposing:

- It involves bi-directional data flow (Opp can update an Account, and an Account can update multiple Opps)
- It involves working on child records (Account is the "parent", and can have many "child" Opportunities)

Bi-directional data flow is a general concern, not really the easiest thing to do correctly, and generally best avoided. The nail in the coffin for workflow though is the need to operate on child records. This may be possible with a combination of Visual Workflow and Process Builder (though I don't think I'd recommend that).

If you must do this, a trigger (well, 2 triggers, one on Account, another on Opportunity) would be how I'd do it. If you're new to basically any feature or concept in Salesforce, https://trailhead.salesforce.com is where you should start your journey. There is [a module dedicated to Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) which will at the very least get you going in the right direction.

Honestly though, I think what you're suggesting is trying to force a square peg through a round hole. Perhaps using the `Contract` SObject to represent/hold the signed NDAs, an Approval Processes (to approve the NDA and update the related account), and a validation rule (only allow an Opp to be closed - won if the Account shows that the NDA is signed) would be a better approach for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I appreciate this comment so much, I think this is the best approach